# NodeJS ssh2 Previous Commands Persisting

Tags: node.js, express, ssh2

I am using ssh2 library with express js. The client sends a POST request to the express api, which then should create some file, and then uses ssh2 to copy the file from one directory to another, and eventually will execute another shell command on the file.

However I am running into an issue with just the copy. When making requests, the files increment their number in the file name, however ssh2 continues to send the previous files again and again.

```
Jul 21 07:13 roi00754.edi
Jul 21 07:13 roi00755.edi
Jul 21 07:13 roi00757.edi
Jul 21 07:13 roi00756.edi
Jul 21 07:13 roi00758.edi
Jul 21 07:13 roi00760.edi
Jul 21 07:13 roi00759.edi
Jul 21 07:13 roi00761.edi
```

```
                ssh.on('ready', () => {
                    console.log('Client :: ready');
                    ssh.exec(
                        `
                        cp ${conf.remote_rollcreate_dir_full}${rollcreate_ord_filename} ${remote_edi_ord_dir_full}${edi_ord_filename}\n
                        `,
                        (err, stream) => {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            stream.on('close', (code, signal) => {
                                console.log('Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
                                ssh.end();
                            })
                            stream.on('data', (data) => {
                                console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
                            }).stderr.on('data', (data) => {
                                console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
                            });
                            stream.end(`exit\n`)
                        }
                    );
                }).connect(ssh_config);
```

Any ideas how to get this to fully close the connection before executing the next command?

Answer (score 1):

The solution appears to be using `.once('ready' ...` instead of `.on('ready' ...`

See https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/issues/717